# IBM Cloud API Connect Secure Gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, apic

Recently, I started seeing an issue when trying to setup secure gateway within API Connect on IBM Cloud, I previously had it working but looks like they changed this wizard interface and its broken since then
here is what I did to recreate the issue:

1. Setup new APIC instance on IBM Cloud
2. API connect Manager UI > Admin > Secure Gateways > Add (name & save)
3. once created, in Secure Gateway Clients section, click on +Set Up

I see no ID or Token generated
no matter what type of client I choose (DataPower, Docker or Installer)

Anyone facing the same issue?

[Empty ID and Token when trying to setup Secure Gateway Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEMZZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out that creating SecureGateway from within the APIC is deprecated feature anyway.

you will need to create standalone SecureGateway resource on Bluemix and call it from your API assembly.

here is the instructions

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.apionprem.doc/task_api_secure_gateway.html